# SQL Server 2008 - Aggregate totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL, this is what I am trying to figure out. Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I have as Input.

```
Number   Start        End          Age
PRB1     1/2/2014     1/2/2014      0
PRB1     1/2/2014     1/3/2014      1
PRB1     1/3/2014     1/6/2014      1
PRB2     1/13/2014    1/14/2014     1
PRB3     1/9/2014     1/9/2014      0 
PRB4     1/22/2014    1/22/2014     0
PRB4     1/25/2014    1/28/2014     1
```

This is the output I am expecting

```
Number      Age
PRB1         2
PRB2         1
PRB3         0
PRB4         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work

```
SELECT number, 
       Sum(age) AS Age 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY number
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77580/4)

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. Understood what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just group by number, sum by age.

```
select number, sum(age) as total
from my_table
group by number
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Sum Aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    NUMBER
    ,SUM(AGE) AS AGE
FROM 
    MYTABLE
GROUP BY 
    NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Number, SUM(Age) AS Age FROM Test GROUP BY Number
```

See `GROUP BY` in more details :

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp